# Saving numpy array into dictionary using loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, dictionary

Below is my loop to loop through a bigger array (sortdata), pull out individual columns, and save those into a dictionary based on its iteration in the loop.  My problem is that this loop is only looping through and saving just one column.  It saves the variabledict[1] array and nothing else.  The sortdata array contains four columns (the first two do not have pertinent data so I omitted them in the code).  There should be a variabledict[0].  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

datavalues = floating number that pertains to total columns

sortdata = large array I am pulling data from

```
for k in range(int(datavalues - 2)):
  datavalloop = sortdata[:][0:,k + 2]
  variabledict = {}
  variabledict[k] = datavalloop
```

Comment: You are resetting `variabledict` to be an empty `dict` inside the loop, so it goes back to `{}` every time, and only the final iteration will leave anything stored in the `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `variabledict = {}` outside loop. It is clearing **dictionary** values to **Null** on every iteration leaving only values of the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Place vaiabledict outside the loop. You are resetting it every time:

```
variabledict = {}
for k in range(int(datavalues - 2)):
    datavalloop = sortdata[:][0:,k + 2]
    variabledict[k] = datavalloop
```